# Force close and not getting the output

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the contact number (which is selected) by user's activity. How to solve this issue? Force close and not getting the output!
I have read many tutorials but this was not so helpful to me!

```
  package com.example.c_p;


    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Set;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1001;
    public static final String DEBUG_TAG = null;
         EditText emailEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.invite_email);
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
        public void doLaunchContactPicker(View view)
        {
        Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
    }
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                switch (requestCode)
                {
                case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:
                    Cursor cursor = null;
                    String phone = "";
                    try {
                        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                        Set<String> keys = extras.keySet();
                        Iterator<String> iterate = keys.iterator();
                        while (iterate.hasNext()) {
                            String key = iterate.next();
                            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, key + "[" + extras.get(key) + "]");
                        }

                        Uri result = data.getData();
                        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Got a contact result: "
                                + result.toString());

                        // get the contact id from the Uri
                        String id = result.getLastPathSegment();


                        cursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id },
                                null);

                        int PhoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);


                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                         phone = cursor.getString(PhoneIdx);

                            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Got number: " + phone);

                        } else {
                            Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, "No results");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Failed to Number", e);
                    } 
                    finally {
                        if (cursor != null) {
                            cursor.close();
                        }

                        emailEntry.setText(phone);

                        if (phone.length() == 0) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "No number found for contact.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }

                    break;
                }

            } else {
                Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, "Warning: activity result not ok");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this

```
  EditText emailEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.invite_email);
```

outside `onCreate`. You will get `NullPointeException`

Change to

```
private EditText emailEntry; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    emailEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.invite_email); 
}
```

`findViewById` looks for a view with the id in the currently inflated layout. You need to set the content to the activity first and then initialize your view in `onCreate`

Comment: Seems to me he would really like the [RoboGuice](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice) library

Comment: @tolgap i don't see anything related to robospice in the tag or in the question. sure you posted the comment on the right post.

Comment: you can use Dependency Injection with RoboGuice (not RoboSpice) and use a kind of similar syntax outside of your `onCreate()`. I'm also not saying he has to use it. It's just a suggestion.

Comment: @tolgap why would you need a third party library if you can use whats provided in the framework and i don't see op mentioning robospice anywhere and your comment should be below the question posted

Comment: Dude what are you ranting on about? I'm simply suggesting something. I'm not saying he NEEDS to use it. And if you could read, you would notice that it's not RoboSpice I'm talking about but RoboGuice.

Comment: @tolgap any way its still not a third party library which i would not recommend if you can achieve the same functionality with the framework. you can leave a comment below the question posted or an answer if you want to suggest something to op.

Comment: sir actually i corrected it but still m not able to run it because the instance emailEntry is giving me an error when i use to set some text to it!! please fix it sir

Comment: sir actually m trying to access a contact's phone number from phone book and setting it to edit box! Please help me in solving it... Very very thank you for responding

Comment: what is RoboGuice blabla  means??? i googled the word is it something abt Cloud??

Answer (score 1):

This line will give you an error

```
EditText emailEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.invite_email);
```

you cannot try to initialize a `View` before setting the content. Initialize it after `setContentView()` like below

```
 EditText emailEntry;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // not until here
    emailEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.invite_email);
```

Since your Views exist in your layout, you can't find them as with findViewById() until you have inflated your layout with an inflater or with setContentView().